# Marking Glottal Closure with OpenEars / PocketSphinx

Tags: speech-recognition, cmusphinx, openears

I just found out about CMUSphinx in a search for a library that can help identify glottal closures.

What is the method for approaching this problem in PocketSphinx or its related OpenEars?

while marking that information is it possible to grab other properties of the voice easily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the method for approaching this problem in PocketSphinx or its related OpenEars?

There is no such method. Pocketsphinx is a speech recognition library. It inputs audio and returns text. It doesn't know anything about glottal stops.

> while marking that information is it possible to grab other properties of the voice easily?

It's not cleer what information are you talking about. If you are interested in pronunciation evaluation, there is a FAQ entry about that:

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/faq#qhow_to_implement_pronunciation_evaluation

There is also ongoing project to implement pronunciation evaluation but it's just started and expected to finish this summer.